# Remove SQL cluster node

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-clustering

I am trying to remove a SQL 2012 cluster node from a Server 2012 R2 machine. However the windows and cluster itself has already been destoyed so when trying to remove the node the setup is erroring out in validation because ...

"The local computer is not a member of a Windows failover cluster"

and

"The SQL Server failover cluster service is not online, or the cluster cannot be accessed from one of it's nodes. To continue determine why the cluster is not online and rerun Setup. Do not rerun the rule because the rule cannot detect a cluster environment".

Does anyone know how to force the removal of a SQL clustered node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's probably too late for you JBone, but I had the same issue and what I did was go into the registry and delete the `ClusterName` key for the instance.  This lets the uninstall see this as a non-clustered instance and you can uninstall as a non-clustered instance through add/remove programs.

The registry key I removed was:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\Cluster:ClusterName

Comment: YES!!! This is the fix. Worked for a clustered instance of SQL2016 where I had destroyed the cluster disks and then wanted to uninstall SQL

Answer (score -1):

To remove a node from an existing SQL Server failover cluster, you must run SQL Server Setup on the node that is to be removed from the SQL Server failover cluster instance.

Follow the instructions http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191545.aspx

Comment: So this is what I am doing, unfortunately I am getting errors and am not able to complete.

Comment: And all the Servers are on the domain? and you logon as a Domain Admin?

Comment: On the step 5 On the Cluster Node Configuration page, do you see a NODE you want to remove?

Comment: The servers are all on the domain and I am admin to this OU. The issue is that the cluster no longer exist. I forced the removal of the sql nodes and destroyed the cluster without removing the nodes from the setup first. I was doing this as experimentation as to what would happen more or less.

Comment: Well obviously there is Right Way and Wrong way uninstalling NODES. Destroying Cluster SERVER (not a good thing to do) but you experimenting...the only thing I can suggest is try using Powershell...see if you can force to uninstall. Good luck

Comment: This only works if your cluster is in good working order. Unfortunately, it looks like one must repair a broken cluster simply to remove it, and be able to uninstall/reinstall MS SQL. This cannot be the right way! (Surely, there's a better way!) :-)